# UIActivityIndicator shows for a split second

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityindicatorview

I am trying to show an spinning activity indicator for my app when the user taps on a button before they are presented with the next view - it kind of works, I see it for a split second

```
@IBOutlet weak var myActivityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!
@IBOutlet weak var eventsbtn: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var pubsbtn: UIButton!
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

    myActivityIndicator.stopAnimating()
    myActivityIndicator.hidden = true
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    eventsbtn.layer.cornerRadius = 8
    pubsbtn.layer.cornerRadius = 8
}



@IBAction func getEvents(sender: AnyObject) {

    myActivityIndicator.hidden = false
    myActivityIndicator.startAnimating()
}
```

Comment: And the question is...?

Comment: Why does it not show when I tap the button? Have I coded it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Refactor your code. You don't need to stop the activity indicator in `viewWillAppear`. You can hide it in `viewDidLoad`. Here's the code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var myActivityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!
@IBOutlet weak var eventsbtn: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var pubsbtn: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    eventsbtn.layer.cornerRadius = 8
    pubsbtn.layer.cornerRadius = 8
    myActivityIndicator.hidden = true

}

@IBAction func getEvents(sender: AnyObject) {

    myActivityIndicator.hidden = false
    myActivityIndicator.startAnimating()
}
```

Make sure that the `IBOutlet` for the activity indicator and `IBAction` for getting events are correctly connected in Interface Builder.

Answer (score 0):

I changed it and it doesn't work, until I go back  in the navigation

`@IBOutlet weak var myActivityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!
    @IBOutlet weak var eventsbtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var pubsbtn: UIButton!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        myActivityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        myActivityIndicator.hidden = true
        eventsbtn.layer.cornerRadius = 8
        pubsbtn.layer.cornerRadius = 8
    }
    @IBAction func getEvents(sender: AnyObject) {
        myActivityIndicator.hidden = false
        myActivityIndicator.startAnimating()
   }`

Answer (score 0):

viewDidAppear is probably a more appropriate place to stop the animation and hide the spinner.